# Thick circle detection

Tags: c#, image-processing, aforge

I have an RGB image.Suppose say I have two circles in it.I want to know which one is filled and which one is not.I followed the following steps:
-imported the image as Bitmap

[image: rgbimage]

-converted into grayscale and used CannyEdgeDetector filter to find the edges. I get the following image

[image: edge]

circle containing the letter "D" gives two edges, where as I need only one circle edge. Secondly, how do I find out which circle is filled and which one is not.

Comment: Not an easy question... What do you know about the circle??? For example, do you know its circle's centre position? Do you know the radius? Is it fixed? Do you know what the circle would contain if it's not empty (letters, shapes, whatever)?

Comment: Actually its a MCQ answer sheet.all circles have letters A-D, some of them are darkened with black pen.After edgedetection, I get three circles,two for upper circle and one for darkened cirle. Yes, I can find the radius,center, or even all the edge points.Now how do I find out which one is filled and which one is not. AND how do i get only 1 edge in the upper edge detected image.

Answer (score 3):

For the MCQ answers sheet, it might be easier to go by positions of the circles.

Just compare stock images of the clear, circled A, B, C and D's to the scanned images and see which differ the most. A simple darkness summation might be enough.

Also: Comparing the circles against each other might be useful too to compensate for a bad/dark/light scan or smudgy paper.

For special cases if the test isn't absolutely sure I'd probably pass it to a human being for further investigation. E.g., when you allow students to undo an answer by circling their second guess or when a student decides to make a real mess by using a bad eraser.

Final tip: make sure you do not accept answers that have the correct circle filled; make sure the other circles are clear at the same time so students can't cheat by filling all circles. (Some professors use a paper mask that overlays all bad answers so they can quickly spot unmarked correct answers. But if the student just marks all answers this fails big time.)

Comment: @Eddie - I added some extra advice

Comment: @ErnodeWeerd that would help,but i need to determine student's roll no. and name using the darkened circle.Not just the correct answers.Anyway thanks.i will give a vote up.

Comment: If you can add an example of the actual form we might be able to provide more help. Roll no and name might be tricky but we can't help without more details

Answer (score 2):

I would not know any "formal" algorithm matching your criteria. I would also doubt that you would find any.

When you say the circles are "darkened", this can be interpreted as this: "Many pixels (above a population threshold) would be black, or at least dark (above a colour threshold).". Based on known circle and radius, I would follow this approach (written in pseudocode but I suppose you get the meaning):

```
//define thresholds
colourThreshold=...
populationThreshold=...

centerPoint = getCircleCenter();
radius = getCircleRadius();
darkPixelsCount = 0;

for(x=centerPoint.X-radius;x<centerPoint.X+radius;x++){
   for(y=centerPoint.Y-sqrt(abs(radius^2-(x - centerPoint.X)^2));centerPoint.Y+sqrt(abs(radius^2-(x - centerPoint.X)^2));y++){

      if (image(x, y) >  colourThreshold){
         darkPixelsCounter++;      

         if(darkPixelsCounter > populationThreshold){
             //If you reach this point, circle has been darkened
             return;
         }

      }
    }
}

//If you reach this point, circle has not been darkened
return;
```

I don't know if it is efficient, or if there is a more elegant way to do it. I suppose you could play with performance and accuracy by moderating the thresholds.

Hope I helped!

Comment: thanks for the answer.But your algorithm counts dark pixels of a square enclosing the circle.Can you help me find dark pixels of the circle only.Its Just Math.

Comment: You are right. I suppose it would change the actual result but nevertheless I will try to alter the code to match a circle...

Comment: @pantelis-natsiavas equation of circle is x^2 +y^2=r^2 
or y=sqrt(r^2-x^2)  
i.e y should range from -sqrt(Absolute(r^2-x^2) to  +sqrt(Absolute(r^2-x^2) Considering (0,0) is the center.

Comment: Would you please check it again? Just to be certain that I don't miss something while writing down the equation. Including the centre point x0,y0 the y would be between the points A: centerPoint.Y-sqrt(abs(radius^2-(x - centerPoint.X)^2)) and B: centerPoint.Y+sqrt(abs(radius^2-(x - centerPoint.X)^2)). Right?

Answer (score 0):

Perform blob detection, with a pixel count

or even simpler count the black pixels

or even simpler and faster, take middle line and count how often it switches from white to black